A username in WordPress that I never created
I'm learning to use WordPress.
In my WordPress, there is always a username with the name "wpcronafxxxxx".
For example: wpcronaf866d7a
I tried to find information related to this on Google but couldn't find it.
I never created this username.
Is it normal for WordPress to create it automatically or what?
The plugins I use:
Advanced Google reCAPTCHA
All in One SEO
Limit Login Attempts Reloaded

One possibility is that you have 'create CMS user' turned on for one of your public profiles, so when someone submits a form it also creates a user. if you don't have any links from the users profile to their civi record, then if you do have access to the db, check the uf_match table to see which civi records they are connected to. If they are not showing in the uf_match table either then it means this is purely a WP issue, not a civicrm issue would be my guess
